# Is the model or a service responsible for defining the default TTL to a new instance of the model?

Tags: java, spring, oop

Here is the thing, I want to add ttl in my Dynamo tables, and it has a default Duration, but I want it to be configurable by properties, for each Spring Profile to have it's own configuration.

```
public Long getTtl() {
    return ttl;
}

public void setTtl(Long ttl) {
    this.ttl = ttl;
}
```

And to populate it correctly I will need to do something like this.

```
entity.setTtl(Instant.now().plus(Duration.from(defaultTTL)).getEpochSecond());
```

this defaultTTL I would load from an @Value or something.

But my question is where to put it. My first instinct was to set in the default constructor, but I don't like to load Spring values in it.

Following the "a code that changes together, belong together."

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I defined the DEFAULT_TTL in a constant in a service for the CRUD operations and set the TTL in the Model's Constructor.

It looks good.